# Plugin to check code vulnerabilities in XQuery code

Tags: github, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-10

We are using XQuery code for our backend implementation with ML 10.The deployment of the code is done using **ml-gradle** plugin and **Jenkins**.The code is stored in Github repository.

The requirement is to check the code violations/vulnerabilities of our XQuery code via scan and fix the issues based on the report.

Please suggest best tools/plugins for the code vulnerability check.

Comment: We have a similar setup and are using SonarQube and this [SonarQube XQuery Plugin](https://github.com/malteseduck/sonar-xquery-plugin) built by some community members. Best of luck!